# How to select next 2 rows after a certain categorical condition is met

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, timestamp

```
| Date   |  Time    | SGN
-----------------------
20201111 | 10:44    |  CB
20201111 | 10:45    |  FF
20201111 | 10:46    |  VW
20201111 | 10:47    |  GG
20201111 | 10:48    |  RR
20201111 | 10:56    |  BB
20201111 | 10:59    |  CB
20201111 | 11:04    |  VW
20201111 | 11:04    |  BB
20201111 | 11:04    |  BR
20201111 | 11:04    |  CB
20201111 | 11:04    |  BB
```

I am looking for 'VW' in specific, and I want to select VW and the next 2 rows just after that, considering it is sorted by DateTime.

So the Output will be:

```
| Date   |  Time    | SGN
-----------------------

20201111 | 10:46    |  VW
20201111 | 10:47    |  GG
20201111 | 10:48    |  RR
20201111 | 11:04    |  VW
20201111 | 11:04    |  BB
20201111 | 11:04    |  BR
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df[df.SGN.where(df.SGN == 'VW').ffill(limit=2).eq('VW')]

#       Date   Time SGN
#2  20201111  10:46  VW
#3  20201111  10:47  GG
#4  20201111  10:48  RR
#7  20201111  11:04  VW
#8  20201111  11:04  BB
#9  20201111  11:04  BR
```

where

1. `df.SGN.where(df.SGN == 'VW')` marks all non-VW values as NA;
2. `.ffill(limit=2)` fill the next 3 rows (self inclusive) as `VW`;
3. `.eq('VW')` creates a boolean to select all rows that meet the condition;

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
s = df['SGN'].eq('VW')
s = s | s.shift(1) | s.shift(2) 
df = df[s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Loop thru the dataframe
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["SGN"] == "VW":
        print(df.loc[index:].head(3))
```

This was the output

```
   Date   Time SGN
2  20201111  10:46  VW
3  20201111  10:47  GG
4  20201111  10:48  RR
       Date   Time SGN
7  20201111  11:04  VW
8  20201111  11:04  BB
9  20201111  11:04  BR
```